# how to NOT show syslog info messages on terminal TTY

Tags: shell, systemd, cron, stdout, rsyslog

I have a home media server in the kitchen (OMV / Debian). I have one physical terminal open - display and keyboard running [`musikcube`](https://github.com/clangen/musikcube) player that shows browses and plays the music library. Looks very cool and works very well, however since recent update screen becomes garbled by periodic messages:

```
[ OK ] Started Run anacron job.
Starting Clean php session files...
[ OK ] Started Clean php session files.
```

And so on...

How do I avoid these outputs on screen (TTY)? They seem to appear to whatever screen is in focus (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F1 or Ctrl-Alt-F3) even without `musikcube` running. Log system is `rsyslog`.

After some digging with `journalctl` I found that the messages originate from systemd (I think) and are at `info` level:

`journalctl /usr/lib/systemd/systemd -p info`

```
2022-11-29T05:39:00+0000 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
2022-11-29T05:39:00+0000 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
2022-11-29T05:39:00+0000 systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
2022-11-29T06:09:00+0000 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
2022-11-29T06:09:00+0000 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
2022-11-29T06:09:00+0000 systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
```

But at that not all the messages make it to terminal screen. From the above messages `phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.` does not appear, but other messages do.

Comment: Do you have entries in `/etc/syslog.conf` for things to log to `*` or to `/dev/console`?

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. What does asterisk mean in your comment, please?

Comment: I admit I'm not 100% sure what a `*` would mean as the destination for logging in `syslog.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply disabling "messages" for particular console: `mesg n`?